# ruby gem statement - what does it do?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I think I have a basic understanding of what require/include statements at the top of a ruby script are doing, like

```
require 'rspec'
```

These statements are easy to google and find relevant results.  But sometimes I have seen a gem statement like

```
gem 'rspec'
```

What does this line do?

Comment: By the way: none of these are statements. Ruby doesn't have statements, only expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ruby code, `gem(gem_name, *requirements)` defined in `Kernel` tells Ruby to load a specific version of `gem_name`. That's useful when you have installed more than one version of the same gem.

For example, if you have installed two versions of `rspec`, say `2.12.0` and `2.13.0`, you can call `gem` before `require` to use specific version. Note that `gem` should come before the `require` call.

```rb
gem 'rspec', '=2.12.0'
require 'rspec'
```

A `gem 'gem_name'` without version uses the latest version on your machine, and that's unnecessary. You can call `require` without `gem` to get the same behavior.

And besides, in Bundler::Dsl, `gem` is used to tell bundler to prepare/install specific version of ruby gems. You'll see that in [Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html)

Answer (score 4):

The original behaviour of `require`, before Rubygems, was to search all the directories listed in the `$LOAD_FILES` variable for the file, and to load the first one it finds that matches. If no matching file was found, `require` would raise a `LoadError`.

Rubygems changes this process. With Rubygems, `require` will search the existing `$LOAD_PATH` as before, but if there is no matching file found then Rubygems will search the installed gems on your machine for a match. If a gem is found that contains a matching file, that gem is *activated*, and then the `$LOAD_PATH` search is repeated. The main effect of activating a gem is that the gems `lib` directory is added to your load path. In this way the second search of the load path will find the file being required.

Normally this will mean that the latest version of a gem that you have installed gets activated. Sometimes you will want to use a different version of a gem, and to do that you can use the [`gem` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-gem). The `gem` method activates a gem, and you can specify the version you want, but doesn’t require any files. When you later require the files you want, you’ll get them from the gem version you specified.

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby, gems are packages with functionality that can be used out of the box (as libraries in other Programming languages).

The gems that you use with your Ruby Project can easily be managed with a tool called   "bundler", just google it. The snippet of code you posted is part of the spec file that bundler uses to install and update all the libraries that you specify for your project.

If you are developing a Ruby on Rails, using gems an managing them with bundler is very common and so to say best practice.

Gems are just great because there are so many useful libraries that extend default functionality, eg of rails, and that you can use out of the box!

For a list of gems, visit rubygems.org

Comment: -1. Half of the answer is incomprehensible gibberish, but it still is obvious that this doesn't answer the question, plus the introductory sentence is blatantly wrong.